# Javascript: How to return or parse an object literal with eval?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval, object-literal

I have a little library that takes strings and constructs objects out of them. For example `'-key val'` creates `{"key": "val"}`. However I'm trying to extend the syntax of the input string to take simple object literals too, such as `'-key "{key: 'val'}"'` which should yield `{"key" : {"key" : "val"}}` however the result is only `{"key" : "val"}`.

Why does eval only return "val" and not the entire object? And is there a safer alternative then my solution?

```
// my code before the fix
var arg = '{key: "val"}'
var result = eval(arg)
// result is "val"
```

Below is my fix, which is very unsafe!

```
const fmt = require('util').format
var arg = '{key: "val"}'
var result = eval(fmt('()=>(%s)', arg))()
// result is { key : "val" }
```

Comment: The `{}` is being treated as a block, and `key` as a label, so this evaluates to `"val"`. To have it evaluated as an object literal, you will need to wrap it in parentheses. That is essentially what your fix does, albeit in a convoluted way. Instead, just do `eval('(' + arg + ')')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{key: "val"}` is a block, and `key:` is a label.

If you want to parse it as an object initializer, use it in a place which expects an expression, e.g.

```
({key: "val"})
0,{key: "val"}
[{key: "val"}][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`var arg = '{key: "val"}'
var result = eval(arg)`
when eval parse it, the '{' will be thought of as code block, and `key:` is a label
so I think you should use
`var arg = '{key:"val"}'
 var result = eval('('+arg+')')
//result {key:"val"}`