# Create object from object literal string

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there an easy way to parse an object literal as a string into a new object?

I'm looking to turn a string like the following:

```
'{ name: "A", list: [] }'
```

Into an object like:

```
{ name: 'A', list: [] }
```

**Note:**

I'm not looking for `JSON.parse()` as it accepts json strings and not object literal strings. I was hoping that `eval` would work but unfortunately it does not.

Comment: Did you research this at all? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/38517452/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/8949274/3001761 suggest just adding parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval` does indeed work, with one tweak: the problem is that the standalone line

```
{ name: 'A', list: [] }
```

gets parsed as the interpreter as *the beginning of a block*, rather than as the start of an object literal. So, just like arrow functions which implicitly return objects need to have parentheses surrounding the objects:

```
arr.map(item => ({ item }))
```

you need to put parentheses around the input string, so that the content inside (that is, the object, which starts with `{`) is parsed properly as an expression:

```js
const input = '{ name: "A", list: [] }';
const obj = eval('(' + input + ')');
console.log(obj);
```

Of course, as with all cases when `eval` is involved, you should be *very sure* that the input is trustworthy first.

Answer (score 1):

While I would never do this IRL, you could perhaps try this:

```
var myObjLiteralString = '{ name: "A", list: [] }';

var myObj;
eval('myObj = ' + myObjLiteralString);

console.log(myObj);
```